# perl6-debug-m spawning moar till system thrashes

Tags: debugging, raku

I installed perl6 on Ubuntu with `rakudobrew` and then `Debugger::UI::CommandLine` with panda but I can't debug because there is no `perl6-debug` command -- only a `perl6-debug-m` command which, when I invoke it on a rather simple script, brings the system to its knees by spawning a huge number of moar tasks.    Any suggestions?

Here's my configuration:

```
$ rakudobrew current
Currently running moar-2015.12
$ which rakudobrew 
/home/jabowery/.rakudobrew/bin/rakudobrew
$ which perl6
/home/jabowery/.rakudobrew/bin/perl6
$ which panda
/home/jabowery/.rakudobrew/bin/panda
$ which perl6-debug-m
/home/jabowery/.rakudobrew/bin/perl6-debug-m
$ perl6 -v
This is Rakudo version 2015.12 built on MoarVM version 2015.12
implementing Perl 6.c.
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using `rakudobrew nuke` and `apt purge rakudo` and then reinstalling rakudobrew after `rm -rf ~/.rakudobrew`.  Reinstalling perl6, panda and `Debugger::UI::CommandLine` led to a working debugger.

Apparently something was wrong with the original installation.